# Z-score calculation from mean and st dev

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, statistics, normal-distribution

I would like to ask whether any popular package like: numpy, scipy, etc has a built in function to calculate Z-Score if I know already crital value, mean and st dev.

I am doing it usually like:

```
def Zscore(xcritical, mean, stdev):
    return (xcritical - mean)/stdev

#example:
xcritical = 73.06
mean = 72
stdev = 0.5

zscore = Zscore(xcritical, mean, stdev)
```

and later I am using `scipy.stats.norm.cdf` to calculate probability of x being lower than xcritical.

```
import scipy.stats as st
print(st.norm.cdf(zscore))
```

I wonder If I can simplify it somehow. I know that there is `scipy.stats.zscore` function but it takes a sample array and not sample statistics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting `Python 3.9`, the standard library provides the [`zscore`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/statistics.html?highlight=zscore#statistics.NormalDist.zscore) function on the [`NormalDist`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/statistics.html?highlight=normaldist#statistics.NormalDist) object as part of the [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/statistics.html) module:

```
NormalDist(mu=72, sigma=.5).zscore(73.06)
# 2.1200000000000045
```

Answer (score 1):

In your question, I am not sure what do you mean by calculating the probability of 'x' being lower than 'xcritical' because you have not defined 'x'. Anyhow, I shall answer how to calculate the z-score for an 'x' value.

Going by the *scipy.stats.norm* documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html), there doesn't seem to be an inbuilt method to calculate the z-score for a value ('xcritical' in your case), given the mean and standard deviation. However, you can calculate the same using inbuilt methods *cdf* and *ppf*. Consider the following snippet (the values are same as you have used in your post, where 'xcritical' is the value for which you wish to calculate z-score):

```
xcritical = 73.06
mean = 72
stdev = 0.5

p = norm.cdf(x=xcritical,loc=mean,scale=stdev)
z_score = norm.ppf(p)
print('The z-score for {} corresonding to {} mean and {} std deviation is: {:.3f}'.format(xcritical,mean,stdev,z_score))
```

Here, we first calculate the cumulative probability 'p' of obtaining 'xcritical' value given 'mean' and 'stdev' using *norm.cdf()*. *norm.cdf()* calculates the percentage of area under a normal distribution curve from negative infinity till an 'x' value ('xritical' in this case). Then, we pass this probability to *norm.ppf()* to obtain the z-score corresponding to that 'x' value. *norm.ppf()* is percent point function which yields the (z)value corresponding to passed lower tail probability in a standard normal distributed curve. The output of this code **2.12** which is same as what you will obtain from the function *Zscore()*.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in just one line; like so:

```
>>> import scipy.stats as st
>>> st.norm(mean, stdev).cdf(xcritical))
```

Answer (score 0):

> The life in hours of a battery is known to be approximately normally distributed with standard deviation σ = 1.25
> hours. A random sample of 10 batteries has a mean life of x =
> 40.5 hours.
> a. Is there evidence to support the claim that battery life
> exceeds 40 hours? Use α = 0.5.

norm.sf, because I want to know the right side of the bell curve to answer if it exceeds the alpha.

```
norm.sf(40.5, loc=40, scale=1.25/np.sqrt(10)) #recall the z score formula
```

> p-value = 0.102

> Ho: u=40 ; Ha: u>40

So the p-value is greater than alpha, so we fail to reject the null hypothesis and conclude that indeed there is evidence to support that the batery life exceeds 40 hours. P-value of 0.10 > 0.05 alpha